# FORTRAN: Control new line on WRITE statement

Tags: matrix, fortran

I need to solve the inverted usual problem with the new line in fortran. Like printing on the screen a matrix for example. I'm using:

```
do i=1,n
 do j=i,m
  write(*, fmt="(f0.2, tr2)", advance="no") matrix(i,j)
 end do
end do
```

In this way it is gonna put the whole matrix in the same line. I need to put each line in its own and I was wondering if there's a elegant way to do that. My solution is:

```
do i=1,n
 do j=i,m
  write(*, fmt="(f0.2, tr2)", advance="no") matrix(i,j)
 end do
 write(*, fmt="(a)") " "    <---------- NOT ELEGANT
end do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I would extract the last write statement, but that is not much more elegant than your solution:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: n=3, m=3
  real    :: matrix(n,m)
  integer :: i, j

  call random_number( matrix )

  do i=1,n
    do j=i,m-1
       write(*, fmt="(f0.2, tr2)", advance="no") matrix(i,j)
    end do
    write(*, fmt="(f0.2, tr2)") matrix(i,m)
  end do

end program
```

If your compiler supports it, Fortran 2008 has a nice feature called the [*unlimited format item.*](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/07/01/doctor-fortran-in-revert-revert-the-end-of-the-format-is-nigh) Then, your problem can be solved with a single `do` loop:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer,parameter :: n=3, m=3
  real    :: matrix(n,m)
  integer :: i

  call random_number( matrix )

  do i=1,n
    write(*, fmt="(*(f0.2, tr2))") matrix(i,i:m)
  enddo ! i

end program
```

Comment: Gfortran from at least version 4.10.0 compiles the 2nd code above. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @Fortranner This feature has been added to gfortran in [2009](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2009-08/msg00197.html)...

Comment: with older Fortran version, just replace * by 99999 for instance